# Java script error in IE11 but in IE9 working properly

Tags: javascript

```
if ((document.getElementById('rank').value != '01') && (document.getElementById('rank').value != '04') && (document.getElementById('CkbxSecondeePartner').checked)) {
  alert('The rank of the employee is not at the Partner level.  Only Active Partners can be on secondment');

  divObj.style.display = 'none'; //hides
  document.getElementById('CkbxSecondeePartner').checked = false;
}
```

Error shows at:

```
((document.getElementById('rank').value != '01') can not read property 'value' of null)
```

Comment: well what does the element with the id of rank look like?

Comment: Or does it exist in the first place?

Comment: Does changing value to text() fix it?

Comment: @JoakimM it wouldn't as `document.getElementById('rank')`  is already `null` it would just result in `can not read property 'text' of null`

Comment: Aha. Thought it was value that was null :(

Answer (score 1):

IE has a [bug](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.ca/2007/08/bug-152-getelementbyid-returns.html) with their `getElementById(id)` implementation (that is [only fixed if you are running in standards mode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/04/10/html-and-dom-standards-compliance-in-ie8-beta-1.aspx)).

In IE, `getElementById(id)` will actually return an element with a matching `name` attribute even though that is a completely invalid match. (again, if not running in standards mode)

Thus if one of the browsers you were testing in was applying a different rendering mode (code may have been served differently or you may have been tampering with the developer tools) you may see different results.

Also if you are not sure if there will be a match, be sure to test for the element first.

```
var rankField = document.getElementById('rank');
if(rankField && rankField.value != '01'){
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest you to validate your elements before to try to access its properties:

```
if (document.getElementById('rank') && document.getElementById('CkbxSecondeePartner')) {
  if ((document.getElementById('rank').value != '01') && (document.getElementById('rank').value != '04') && (document.getElementById('CkbxSecondeePartner').checked)) {
    alert('The rank of the employee is not at the Partner level.  Only Active Partners can be on secondment');

    divObj.style.display = 'none'; //hides
    document.getElementById('CkbxSecondeePartner').checked = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope no one is responding for the issue with IE11. The same script works fine with IE 8 or 9 but not in IE11. The problem with the legacy applications that use javascripts in most of the pages are in trouble.

Instead of 
(document.getElementById('rank').value != '01')

Use
(document.getElementById('rank') != '01')

And this should solve your problem.

The actual issue is, we cannot make this change to the old system with 3 million lines of code and we cannot just make this change everywhere